# Count unique values per row (over index axis, not column wise)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT 10 AS A, 10 AS B, 10 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 20 AS A, 10 AS B, 20 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 30 AS A, 20 AS B, 10 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 40 AS A, 40 AS B, 40 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 50 AS A, 20 AS B, 20 AS C)

SELECT * FROM data;

    A   B   C
0  10  10  10
1  20  10  20
2  30  20  10
3  40  40  40
4  50  20  20
```

Now I want to count the number if unique values **per row** and store this in a new column called `Unique_count`

So my expected output would be:

```
    A   B   C  Unique_count
0  10  10  10             1
1  20  10  20             2
2  30  20  10             3
3  40  40  40             1
4  50  20  20             2
```

I am familiar with `SELECT DISTINCT`. But these are all column wise operations. I can't figure out how to count per row in SQL.

With the `pandas` module in Python it would simply be:

```
data['Unique_count'] = data.nunique(axis=1)
```

---

I have access to a `MS SQL SERVER` or `MySQL SERVER` so answers in both dialects are accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, use a lateral join -- `apply` keyword`:

```
select t.*, v.unique_count
from t cross apply
     (select count(distinct col) as unique_count
      from (values (t.a), (t.b), (t.c)) v(col)
     ) v;
```

A lateral join is a lot like a correlated subquery in the `from` clause -- but more general because the subquery can return more than one column and more than one row.

This version does exactly what it looks like:  it unpivots the columns and then uses `count(distinct)` to count the number of unique values.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use conditional logic:

```
select
    t.*,
    1 + (a <> b) + (a <> c and b<>c) unique_count
from data t
```

This works because MySQL evaluates true/false conditions as 1/0 in numeric context (this features saves us from lengthy `case` expressions here).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWC8H1Num6tgFj4pr5xzPh/0)**:

```
| A   | B   | C   | unique_count |
| --- | --- | --- | ------------ |
| 10  | 10  | 10  | 1            |
| 20  | 10  | 20  | 2            |
| 30  | 20  | 10  | 3            |
| 40  | 40  | 40  | 1            |
| 50  | 20  | 20  | 2            |
```

Comment: So basically the booleans of the two conditions you add up, right?

Comment: @Erfan: yes each condition produces 1 on success (else 0), and values are added. This gives you the count of distinct values across the 3 columns.

Comment: I see, nice out of the box approach!

Comment: Generalizing this to more than 3 columns makes it a bit more complex, right?

Comment: @Barmar: yes, the complexity of the conditional logic increases drastically with the number of columns; your solution is a better pick if there are a lot of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` column to the table. Then you can use `UNION` to pivot the columns into rows, then `COUNT(*)` to get the counts. Then join that with the original table.

Note that you don't need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` because `UNION DISTINCT` removes duplicates.

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT 0 AS id, 10 AS A, 10 AS B, 10 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS id, 20 AS A, 10 AS B, 20 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, 30 AS A, 20 AS B, 10 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS id, 40 AS A, 40 AS B, 40 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS id, 50 AS A, 20 AS B, 20 AS C)

SELECT t1.*, t2.unique_count
FROM data AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS unique_count
    FROM (
        SELECT id, A AS datum FROM data
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT id, B AS datum FROM data
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT id, C AS datum FROM data) AS x
    GROUP BY id) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```